# Sending a custom header with ZEND_HTTP_CLIENT

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-http-client

How can I send a custom header with the `ZEND_HTTP_CLIENT`. I am trying to send a variable `key` with a certain value, that I will check later for authenticity

I've tried this

```
       $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://localhost/v3/files/');
       $client->setHeaders('Content-type','multipart/form-data');
       $client->setHeaders('key','XXXxXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

       $client->setParameterPost('document_id', $id);
       $client->setParameterPost('type_id', $docType['type']);
       $client->setParameterPost('file', $form->file);
       $response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
```

and this

```
  $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://localhost/v3/files/');
   $client->setHeaders(array(
      'Content-type','multipart/form-data',
      'key','XXXxXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));

       $client->setParameterPost('document_id', $id);
       $client->setParameterPost('type_id', $docType['type']);
       $client->setParameterPost('file', $form->file);
       $response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
```

but it doesnt seem to work. It says `key` is not a valid type. 
I want to send a custom header like this (similar to what happens when you set headers with the Postman client). 
Is this possible?

Comment: You should know it is a bad practice to use non-standard headers without an `X-` prefix. If you have any control over what the server expects, I would suggest using `X-Key` instead of just `Key`, as is defined in the HTTP RFC.

Comment: Actually you should not use any X- prefixes, as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with add a config param like this:

```
 $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://localhost/v3/files/', array('strict' => false));
```